# Generating Description From Container Type

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Thats My Data Set. I Want Finall Result Like This

```
LedgerID   Unit  PerUnitRs     Weight  BillNo  CarNo   Description
  33        1      110.00      4520    001192          BOX 1  700  1
                                                       Drums  3320 1
                                                       Tapi   500  1
```

Weight is Calculated by summing the netweight and Description is (ContainerType) + (NetWeight) + (Unit)

Thats My Query

```
SELECT LedgerId,Unit,PerUnitRs,SUM(NetWeight) [Weight], BillNo,CarNo FROM RawMaterial
  GROUP BY LedgerId,Unit,PerUnitRs, BillNo,CarNo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Done it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LedgerId,Unit,PerUnitRs,SUM(NetWeight) [NetWeight], BillNo,CarNo,
   STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [ContainerType] + ' ' + CAST([NetWeight] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' + CAST([Unit] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM RawMaterial
    WHERE (LedgerId = Results.LedgerId) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS Description

   FROM RawMaterial Results
  GROUP BY LedgerId,Unit,PerUnitRs, BillNo,CarNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query was close, all the rest you needed was to add the description:

```
SELECT  LedgerId,Unit,PerUnitRs,SUM(NetWeight) [Weight], BillNo,CarNo, 
        ContainerType + CAST(SUM(NetWeight) AS VARCHAR(100)) + CAST(Unit AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Description
FROM    RawMaterial
GROUP BY LedgerId,Unit,PerUnitRs, BillNo,CarNo, ContainerType
```

Regarding the formating with grouped information showing only once, i`m afraid that's not sql's job to do, sql will return a table, the way you're formating your data to display it, needs to be done in application.